# I'm trying to run my project but I have faced this issue

Tags: flutter, xcode

[image]

Xcode version is (14.3) and flutter version is (3.7.10) macOs 13.3
but I don't why I'm getting this error even delete pod file and then install, update pods... I'm stuck here from last 6 hours

Comment: Downgrade your Xcode to 14.2

Answer (score 0):

in your pod file replace this

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

to

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.generated_projects.each do |project|
        project.targets.each do |target|
            target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '13.0'
             end
        end
 end
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

This is the solution for running not for build

Comment: I tried but not working for me :(

Comment: Remove the pod file, then retest; it should work.

Comment: "Lexical or Preprocessor Issue (Xcode): 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found"
now another found :D

Comment: try running the command "flutter clean" in your project directory to clear any cached data.
Next, run the command "flutter pub get" to download and install any missing dependencies in your project.

Comment: I did same thing even update pods but not working

Comment: for now, the best thing is to Downgrade your Xcode to 14.2

Comment: https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_14.2/Xcode_14.2.xip

Comment: I did but same error still exisit